# Electron / Browser: Detect when the app is opened again from taskbar (after being minimized)

Tags: javascript, browser, electron, minimize

I'm struggling to find a solution to my problem - I am developing an Electron app and I really need to find a way (with JavaScript) to detect when the user opens the app again from the taskbar when it's minimized.
Any kind of help is appreciated!

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
        document.getElementById("minApp").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            document.getElementById('minApp').style.opacity = '0.55';
            document.getElementById('minApp').onmouseover = function() {
                document.getElementById('minApp').style.opacity = '0.55'; 
            }
            document.getElementById('minApp').onmouseout = function() {
                document.getElementById('minApp').style.opacity = '0.55'; 
            }
            var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            window.minimize();
        });
        document.getElementById("closeApp").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            window.close();
        });
        var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
        window.on('restore', () => {
            document.getElementById('minApp').style.opacity = '0.55';
            document.getElementById('minApp').onmouseover = function() {
                document.getElementById('minApp').style.opacity = '1'; 
            }
            document.getElementById('minApp').onmouseout = function() {
                document.getElementById('minApp').style.opacity = '0.55'; 
            }
            alert(1);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`restore`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-restore) event for your `BrowserWindow` object.

> Emitted when the window is restored from a minimized state.

```js
mainWindow.on('restore', () => {
  console.log('Restoring window from minimization');
})
```

Comment: Hello! This sadly didn't work but I'm optimistic that it can be fixed; since my app goes through different pages and I'm currently not working on the startup / default page of the app, I guess the issue is something else. I'm going to post my code above for more information.

Comment: Are all the pages on the same window, or are you instantiating different `BrowserWindow` instances for each?

Comment: They are on the same one, though it seems like the problem is in the syntax. It can't read "mainWindow.on" for some reason.

Comment: Does the `restore` event trigger if you add the listener in the main process instead?

Comment: No, it doesn't, sadly. I will try different ways and let people know if any of them works, though it seems like popular apps like Discord are also facing this issue.